# HTML/jQuery: Semantically tagging glossary-enabled terms in body copy

Tags: jquery, semantics, semantic-markup

All,

I'm working on adding a glossary to an existing site. I'm planning to set up individual .html fragments with individual definitions, then use a jQuery Tooltip plugin attached to individual terms in the copy that will pull the .html fragment and render it.

This avoids having to pre-load many definitions into each page's HTML (I don't have a server-side dynamic language at my disposal - long story - so this is the best way I've thought of to do this).

My initial thought is to use `<dt>` tags around terms that have definitions, and then have jQuery attach the tooltip to each term. So my markup would remain very clean and simple:

`<p>Lorem ipsum dolor <dt>amet</dt></p>`

This is nice because I am not using the dt/dl/dd tags anywhere else on the site, nor do I plan to.

Is this a reasonable solution? Or is it incorrect to use a `<dt>` when it is not inside a `<dl>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an acceptable solution, although it is not technically valid HTML to have, as you said, a dt inside a dl. If you need it to be valid HTML, use the DFN tag.

Comment: Great. I'll use DFN so it will validate properly. Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

If you going for semantics `<dt>` should be contained in a `<dl>` per the W3C.  Maybe use a regular span tag with a good class name like `<span class="defineable">[term]</span>`